# Rewrite rule for a folder/page name without an extension

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule that doesn't seem to be working as I anticipated. I'm redirected to a 404. It seems to only work if I have an extension on the page.

`/folder/page.html works` but `/folder/page doesn't`.

```
<rule name="preact" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(docs)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Read FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: The rule should works fine with a non-asp.net application. You should look into  your failed request tracing log and check whether extensionless handler blocked the rewrite and return 404 error.Please make sure that route has been ignored by your asp.net pipeline